# How can I use static methods to pass auth tokens to an API class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, redux-saga

I wrote an API `class` that I use with redux saga to separate the actual network calls from the sagas, and that class looks somewhat like this:

```
    export default class ApiService {

        constructor(bearer) {
            this.instance = axios.create({
                ...
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${bearer}`
                }
            })
        }

        fetchPosts = async () => {
            const response = this.instance.get(.....)
        }
        ........
    }
```

However in my sagas I have to instantiate a new object every time within a saga like this:

```
    const { accessToken } = yield select(getAuth)
    const apiService = new ApiService(accessToken);
```

Is there a better approach I could take with this so I can remove those 2 lines of code from every saga call and still make sure that the object will have the correct bearer token?

Thanks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a function which returns new api service only if it's the first call or the token is updated.

### api.js

```
let api;
let token;

const isNewToken = (newToken) => newToken !== token;
const getApi = (newToken) => {
  const isTokenUpdated = newToken !== token;
  const shouldCreateService = !api || isTokenUpdated;

  if (shouldCreateService) {
    api = new ApiService(newToken);
  }

  return api;
}

export { getApi };
```

Then create some helper generators

```
function* retrieveToken() {
  return yield select(getAuth);
}

function* resolveApi() {
  const token = yield retrieveToken();
  return getApi(token); // getApi from api.js
}
```

Then in your main sagas you can use it like this:

```
function* fetchPostsSaga() {
  const api = yield resolveApi();
  // Rest of code using api
  ...
}
```

---

*Since the authorization token is stored in the **Redux State** the creation of the **ApiService** is bound to **Redux** lifecycle.
If possible I would move retrieval of a **token** outside of **Redux**.*

Comment: The reason why I didn't mention static classes is that updating values in static classes is a code smell and I would avoid that at all costs.

Comment: This is awesome! exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.  Can you quickly explain a little more about what you meant about the apiService being bound to the Redux lifecycle?  I understand that I cant initialize a new apiService without redux, but how would I avoid this?

Comment: Please note that this is just my personal opinion (which might be flawed).
I believe making API calls should be possible even outside of Redux.

This can be achieved by moving token creation and storage outside of redux actions and sagas. If needed the token can always be pushed into the redux state (via an action and reducer)

Answer (score 1):

replace your bearer with a class variable:

```
export default class ApiService {

  constructor(bearer) {

    this.instance = axios.create({
      ...
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${ApiService.bearer}`
      }
    })
  }

  fetchPosts = async () => {
    const response = this.instance.get(.....)
  }
  ........
}
```

and somewhere just initialise it one time before you use it like this:

```
ApiService.bearer = "my bearer";
```